# htaccess error page for non existing pathname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling

I'm not sure what it is called if it is an error 404, 301, 500 or what when someone tries to go to a non existing url pathname of the current website. This is what I have so far for my HTACCESS page, just learning this like literally on my second day of it.

```
# Rewrite Base
  RewriteBase /
# custom 404
  ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
# No visual index
  IndexIgnore *
# Add www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hostname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# Cache Files for 1 week
  <FilesMatch ".(xml|txt|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, proxy-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
```

Im basically trying to find out the coolest things you can do with htaccess I've always been a front end guy and now walking the park of back end dev. Any one can help me with exactly I am looking for, and which errors are for what as I've tried googling this all and the explanations were not very clear

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what information exactly do you need, though.

The 404 message is self-explanatory - Not Found.

301 and 302 are redirects.

The 500 is an Internal Server Error. This one deserves more attention as it can be caused by numerous things. Most common causes are incorrect permissions/ownership of files, exceeding server resources, hitting limits or coding problems etc.

Using the .htaccess you can specify custom error pages and create prettier errors that can be amusing for the customers/visitors and serve them alternative content.

If you have a more specific question, I think we will be able to better help you.

Comment: Hey thank you for the information. I will make a 500, is it the same as assigning the 404? And 301 and 302 are redirects? Saying if you change urls/domain names... what if say someone types in www.hostname.com/incorrectpath  what kind of error is that? Just a 404

Comment: Yes, creating a custom 500 error page is done the same way it is done for the 404. You might also want to do one for 403 - Forbidden. This error usually shows when you either miss your index in the directory that you are trying to access or you have issues with file permissions. 403 could be related to mod_security as well if you have that installed.

Comment: Thanks for that information, a little late but hey, I'm still active lol.